# Is it possible to change discord bot server profile?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Discord added these discord server profiles where you can change your profile picture.
Is it possible to do that on discord.js? If yes, how?

Comment: Server profiles are such a new thing in Discord that the API does not support it yet.. hopefully in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it looks like discord.js doesn't support this feature yet (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setAvatar) so you can't do it using discord.js for now

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking around and I believe I have a solution. View this GitHub issue submission https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1054. Hope this helps! Mainly pointing at this comment on the GitHub, "if (message.content === "botavatar") client.user.setAvatar('./avatar.png'); etc."

Comment: I already checked that, but apparently that is to set the client avatar globally, and i checked this new feature on discord that is the server profile, which you can choose a specific avatar for that server, and i was wondering if there was a way to make a server profile picture only for the bot.
Thanks for the answer btw!